# Graphics tablet monitor Bosto 22U Mini does not work on 15.04

Tags: unity, 15.04, multiple-monitors, graphics-tablet

It used to work on different installs on the very same hardware, but now it maps to both the laptop screen and the actual tablet screen. I tried using `xrestrict` to no degree of success, neither any kind of reinstall or upgrade made any difference. It seems to work on `Kubuntu`, so it seems to be an Ubuntu `Unity` specific problem. I just can't get used to `KDE`, so priority here is to solve this on Unity....

`Running xinput list results on UNIPEN TABLET id=11`, I tried running this on `xrestrict` but I do not know how to check the `enter code here`-c variable for the `CTRC` id of the monitor....

Answer (score 0):

This sounds like the typical extended desktop 'problem' everyone has with pen devices. Actually Xinput system has a Coordinate Transformation Matrix that should be used to restrict the area of your desktop. But it's annoying to re-calculate and enter this matrix by hand every time you change your screen configuration. So just use this GUI tool here to select which screen to use with your pen or touch device:

http://wenhsinjen.github.io/ptxconf/

We just started this project so let us know if it works for you or not.  We'll fix it straight away if there is a problem.

[configuration menu](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FsDjf.jpg)